# Learning jQuery, 4th Edition (Jonathan Chaffer, Karl Swedberg) - need help about exercise at the end of chapter 2

Tags: jquery

Can somebody help me to resolve these two exercises at the end of chapter 2 of book Learning jQuery, 4th Edition http://www.packtpub.com/learning-jquery-with-simple-javascript-techniques-fourth-edition/book ?

**First exercise:** Select all the list items (<li>s) containing a link (). Add the class afterlink to the sibling list items that follow the ones selected.

**Second exercise** Add the class tragedy to the closest ancestor  of
any .pdf link.

HTML code of the page is below:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Selected Shakespeare Plays</title>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="02.css" type="text/css" />

    <script src="jquery.js"></script>
    <script src="02.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="container">
      <h2>Selected Shakespeare Plays</h2>
      <ul id="selected-plays" class="clear-after">
        <li>Comedies
          <ul>
            <li><a href="/asyoulikeit/">As You Like It</a></li>
            <li>All's Well That Ends Well</li>
            <li>A Midsummer Night's Dream</li>
            <li>Twelfth Night</li>
          </ul>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="/asyoulikeit/">As You Like It</a></li>
            <li>All's Well That Ends Well</li>
            <li>A Midsummer Night's Dream</li>
            <li>Twelfth Night</li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li>Tragedies
          <ul>
            <li><a href="hamlet.pdf">Hamlet</a></li>
            <li>Macbeth</li>
            <li>Romeo and Juliet</li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li>Histories
          <ul>
            <li>Henry IV (<a href="mailto:henryiv@king.co.uk">email</a>)
              <ul>
                <li>Part I</li>
                <li>Part II</li>
              </ul>
            </li>
            <li><a href="http://www.shakespeare.co.uk/henryv.htm">Henry V</a></li>
            <li>Richard II</li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

This is my code, but I'm not sure that is correct!

```
$('li ul').each(function(i,d){
        if($(d).has('a[href$=".pdf"]').length==1){
            $($('li ul').get(i+1)).addClass('tragedy');
        }
    });

$('li ul li').has('a').addClass('afterlink');
```

CSS classes:

```
li.afterlink {
  border-right: 4px solid #090;
}
ul.tragedy {
  border: 1px solid #999;
}
```

Comment: Have you run it? Does it work? Does it use the techniques shown in that chapter?

Comment: Yes, of course. It works, but what? I'm new with jQuery.This is my first book that I started to read about jQ. Techniques that are shown in chapter 2 are only sufficient for exercses 1, 2 and 3. Exercises 4 and 5 are challenge!

Comment: But if it works then it's "correct," or is at least one correct approach. But given that it works, what's your question; what are you looking for help with? A 'better' (faster/more efficient) approach?

Comment: I don't know if I've answered on the task.

Answer (score 0):

I'm also reading this book right now and just found a solution mush easier than yours (to be honest I didn't try your code to check if it works). Here's my solution for the challenges:

> $('li').children('a').parent('li').nextAll('li').addClass('afterlink');
>
> $('li a[href$=".pdf"]').closest('ul').addClass('tragedy');

Hope it will be useful.

Answer (score 0):

My solution for the first one. It works.

```
$('li').find('a').parent().nextAll().addClass('afterlink');
```

Answer (score 0):

My solutions are the following:

```
// 4. Challenge: Select all the list items (<li>s) containing a link (<a>). 
// Add the class afterlink to the sibling list items that follow the ones 
// selected.
$("li > a").parent().next().addClass("afterlink");

// 5. Challenge: Add the class tragedy to the closest ancestor <ul> of any 
// .pdf link.
$("a[href$='.pdf']").closest("ul").addClass("tragedy");
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Select all the list items `<li>` containing a link `a`.

   - `const li = $('li').filter('> a')`
2. Add the class `afterlink` to the sibling list items that follow the
   ones selected

   - `li.each((index, element) => $(element).next().addClass('afterlink'));`
3. Add the class `tragedy` to the closest ancestor of any .pdf link

   - `$('a[href$=".pdf"]').each((index, element) => $(element).parent().addClass('tragedy'));`